# Getting Maven (M2e and m2e wtp) plugins for use in Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e-wtp

I just installed eclipse 3.7.2 and was trying to get Maven plugins for it.
 I used Help->Install New Software and used this website to work with:
http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/juno/
I waited for  4 items to show up including:

2) Maven Intgration for Eclipse

3) Maven Itegration for WTP

and clicked those 2 (middle items). To my chagrin, the result was this:

```
The operation cannot be completed.   See the details.
Details:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
```

I saw that someone else saw this when they were on eclipse 3.6.2 and they no longer saw the error after upgrading to 3.7.
But, I would prefer to use 3.7.2 as it works well with other plugins that I need.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. install m2e plugin
2. then install m2e-wtp plugin

It should work. I didn't test using 3.7.x, but it's working with 4.x

Comment: @Reddy The problem seems to be another missing dependency. Installing bot should work but `m2e - slf4j over logback logging` is not found in the repositories.

Comment: Does Indigo already have the marketplace or is it only since Juno? If it's there, try installing m2e using the marketplace.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem. The latest m2e plugin no longer works with Indigo (3.7.2)

However, there is an archive page here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags. This page has a list of old versions of the plugin. I just successfully installed version 1.0 SR2.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, I installed successfully version 1.3.1 from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424

Answer (score 1):

I have added the below link in "Install New Software" in Indigo.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424

I got two options M2E and SLF4j. Accept them .. After download ..Click Restart.. .

For more versions use the below URL's

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/m2e-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Had  the same  problem  with   Indigo Release 2  and this  m2e  update  site  worked  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/?d